# Why is instantaneous velocity of particle on circular disc perpendicular to position vector taking point of contact as origin during rolling motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, rotational-kinematics

[image: Pure rolling motion of circular disc]
Why is P<sub>0</sub>P<sub>2</sub> perpendicular to velocity vector $\vec{v}_2$ in the diagram?

Comment: are you asking for the velocity or why it is perpendicular?

Comment: Why is it perpendicular

Comment: Then edit the title of your question...

Comment: Changed the title

Answer (score 1):

> Why is instantaneous velocity of particle on circular disc perpendicular to position vector taking point of contact as origin during rolling motion

It is because you have assumed that the circular disc is a rigid body and the whole disc is instantaneously rotating about the point of contact $P_0$.

Part of the disc which I shall call "Rod" $P_2P_0$ is **rigid** and instantaneously rotating about point $P_0$ which means that the velocity of any point on the "rod", eg $\vec v_2$, must be perpendicular to radial vector $\vec{P_0P_2}$.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

We need to prove that $$(\vec\omega \times \vec r_2+\vec v_{cm}).(\vec r_2+ \vec{OP_0})=0$$
The very first and last term vanish on expansion so that what we need to prove becomes
$$(\vec\omega \times \vec r_2).\vec{OP_0}+\vec v_{cm}.\vec r_2=0$$
where $|\vec v_{cm}|=|(\vec\omega \times \vec{OP_0})|=|\vec\omega||\vec{OP_0}|$ and $|(\vec\omega \times \vec r_2)|=|\vec\omega||\vec r_2|$, so that the above expression becomes$$|\vec\omega||\vec r_2||\vec{OP_0}|\cos(180^{\circ}-\theta)+|\vec\omega||\vec{OP_0}||\vec r_2|\cos(\theta)=0$$
(Hence Proved)